# ¿Por qué recibo el error Unable to create output en servidor linux cuando uso MPDF?

Tags: php, linux, mpdf

Acabo de migrar de servidor y me he topado con un problema con MPDF. Resulta ser que tengo un script que crea documentos pdf y los guarda en una carpeta dentro de mi servidor llamada **documentos**

Ya me he asegurado de darle los permisos necesarios a mi carpeta. Sus permisos son `777`.

No sé si tenga algo que ver con los permisos de las carpetas padres ya que éstas sí tienen diferentes permisos.

El error que me devuelve mpdf es el siguiente:

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>
> Type: MpdfException
>
> Message: Unable to create output file:
>   /home/xxxxxxxxxxxx/domains/erp.xxxxxxxxxxx.mx/public_html/application/controllers/../../assets/cdn/documentos/5e0ce5c76665a20200101123239.pdf

Como más información, ocupo Ubuntu Server 18.04.

La parte de mi script php que funciona en otro servidor con cpanel (pero que no funciona en este nuevo servidor con Ubuntu 18.04) es el siguiente:

```
$path_name = __DIR__ . "/../../assets/cdn/documentos/" . $file_name . ".pdf";

$mpdf->Output($path_name, "F");
```

Espero puedan echarme una mano a saber cómo solucionarlo, ya intenté borrar y crear la carpeta por consola, por ftp y no funciona. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de haber lidiado aquel día con múltiples soluciones, lo último y único que me sirvió fue volver a crear todas las carpetas a las que hago referencia para guardar mi pdf.

Es decir, de acuerdo a esta dirección:

```
$path_name = __DIR__ . "/../../assets/cdn/documentos/" . $file_name . ".pdf";
```

Dentro de mi servidor tuve que crear las carpetas de `cdn` y `documentos` de la forma en la que indicaba mi ruta a guardar.

```
application
|----------- controllers
|----------------------- MiControlador.php
assets
|------------cdn
|---------------documentos
```

Con esto se solucionó, ya que al borrarlas y crearlas de nuevo se crearon todas las carpetas con los mismos permisos.